# c++ declaring a function with ostream in class header

Tags: c++, class, istream, ostream

I am having problems declaring a class function from the header file, am not sure how it should be formatted in the header. The purpose of this is to save class object data into a file, to be able to read back in later.

employee.h

```
void writedata(ofstream);
```

employee.cpp

```
void Employee::writedata(ofstream& employeewrite)
{
}
```

Employeewrite is the ostream object I declared in main

main.cpp

```
ofstream employeewrite("c:\\test\test.txt");
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look closer at the types in your first two code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *declaring* `writedata` to take a `ofstream` in your header, but *defining* it to take an `ofstream&` (a reference to an `ofstream`) in the source file.  Make them match up.